# Paypal : How to get Original Transaction Id from Sandbox?

Tags: php, paypal, transactions, paypal-sandbox, payment

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_history-details-from-hub&id=76C11569N98512058
Original Tansaction Id is: 8F998724VR277443T

Which can't be find over here.

I have old order but can't get originial transaction id. As it has Merchant Transaction Id & Customer Transaction Id.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Login to merchant PayPal sandbox account and open the original authorization details, here you will see the reauthorization id also. In your case, the original authorization id is 8F998724VR277443T and the reauthorization id is 1LR38328B6097360L. You may get this reauthorization id from the successful reauthorization API response or log in to merchant sandbox account and search original authorization details then you will get the reauthorization id details as well.

Comment: It's not about Reauthorization

Comment: Can you please elaborate your issue?

Comment: How to get Original Transaction Id from Paypal Sandbox as Sandbox shows Merchant Transaction Id not Customer Transaction Id?

Comment: PayPal will not share the customer side transaction to the merchant.